# How to iterate csv file using Powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with multiple columns and want to iterate particular column data.
For instance, I want to iterate the name column to find the particular filename extension and mark the corresponding fileid from neighboring column.

How to achieve this in PowerShell?
also, why can't I do the same using javascript ? is there any particular reason to use PowerShell for this task.

[image]

From the above image, I want to iterate the name column and check for the particular file extension, if find a match, then note the corresponding file id from the File_id column.

I hope requirement is clear.
Looking forward to hearing from the community!

Thanks,
Krishna p

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `csv` here? It's hard to tell without looking at the actual data. Also see PowerShell [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv).

Comment: @Krishna Take a look import csv and foreach, I am sure you will find something on google about that. There is no special reason for using powershell, but powershell is easy to use and is preinstalled on every windows client.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path '.\MyFile.csv'
$csv |? Name -Like '*.pdf' | select file_id
```